# Запуск программы из консоли ubuntu и запуск через exec() php выдают различные результаты

Tags: скрипт, php, ubuntu, exec

Есть скрипт на perl, который генерирует картинку из текста. Проблема в том, что скрипт выдает различные результаты при запуске его из консоли Ubuntu и запуске через функцию exec(). На выходе в картинке отсутствуют русские символы. Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: Где-то проблемы с кодировкой

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего проблема в пользователях и правах доступа.
Скрипт php выполняет другой пользователь, у которого нет доступа к шрифтам с русскими символами!